# Best password management for SP2007

Tags: 2007, forms-authentication

I have a sharepoint site(2007) where there is a document library that needs to be shared between the members of the site and a group of 20 that are not. What would the best way to go about this? At the moment I am thinking form based authentication, would this be ok?

Comment: what you mean by a member of site and a group of 20? member of sites mean internal user(employee) and a group of 20 are external users not part of AD?

Comment: the members use the windows authentication and group of 20 are external partners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to provide access of those 20 groups into SharePoint. For that you can use FBA or AD authentication.

Once the users/groups are inside SharePoint you can create SharePoint Group for setting up proper permission to the Document Library.